# Why do we use "PipeTransform" in custom pipes?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my custom pipe:

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dc'
})
export class DcPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!value) return value;

    return value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + txt.substr(1).toUpperCase();
    });
  }
}
```

What's the purpose of using `implements PipeTransform` in a class declaration?

From what I see is working even without this part.

Answer (score 5):

`PipeTransform` is an interface: https://angular.io/api/core/PipeTransform

Including it and using `implements PipeTransform` ensures that your class will implement the required `transform` method and conform to its interface (specifically requiring the first `value` parameter ... it doesn't do much else).

Conforming to the interface catches possible runtime errors (during transpile time) including but possibly not limited to:

- Not implementing `transform` at all
- Not returning a value from `transform`

This is similar to `implements OnInit` / `ngOnInit`. You don't *have* to implement it for the code to work, but it's a good practice.

Comment: fine..could you tell more about this? i did not get it clearly

Comment: @PalzPal what else would you like to know?

Comment: @Pills... purpose of "PipeTransform" method.. i'm not able to follow..can u explain with an example?

Comment: @PalzPal PipeTransform is not a method; it's an interface: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the API definition: https://angular.io/api/core/PipeTransform

Link to the code behind: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.3/packages/core/src/change_detection/pipe_transform.ts#L1-L38

PipeTransform is a simple interface, it's describing what should be expected expectations of implementation, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry meant to add this as well, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.3/packages/core/src/change_detection/pipe_transform.ts#L1-L38
That is the actual code behind and reading the comments will give you a better idea.